# Eliminate $\theta$ from the equations $\frac{\cos(\alpha-3\theta)}{\cos^3\theta}=\frac{\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin^3\theta}=m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the equations
> $$\frac{\cos(\alpha-3\theta)}{\cos^3\theta}=\frac{\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin^3\theta}=m$$

Ans: $m^2+m\cos\alpha-2=0$.

---

I tried using the following two identities:
$$\cos(3\theta)=4\cos^3(\theta)-3\cos(\theta)$$
$$\sin(3\theta)=3\sin(\theta)-4\sin^3(\theta)$$
but these didn't help much. I am sure that this is a simple problem but I am unable to figure out the right approach to solve it. :(

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for this challenging question. My idea was to convert eveything in $tan$ format, and equate to m. Still solving though..

Comment: Shouldn't then be $\frac{\cos(\alpha-3\theta)}{\cos^3\theta}-\frac{\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin^3 \theta}=0$? [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427enk0vhui2t6) doesn't support that in general, or what did I get wrong?

Comment: i haven't been able to eliminate $\theta$, but I did eliminate $\alpha$ and found that $m=\csc{3\theta}+\sec{3\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle\sin(A-B),\cos(A-B)$ and on rearrangement we have $$\cos\alpha\cos3\theta+\sin\alpha\sin3\theta-m\cos^3\theta=0\ \ \  \ (1)$$

$$\cos\alpha\sin3\theta-\sin\alpha\cos3\theta+m\sin^3\theta=0\ \ \  \ (2)$$

Solving for $\displaystyle\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha,$

$\displaystyle\dfrac{\cos\alpha}m=\cos^3\theta\cos3\theta-\sin^3\theta\sin3\theta$

$\displaystyle=\cos^3\theta(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta)-\sin^3\theta(3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta)$

$\displaystyle=4(\cos^6\theta+\sin^6\theta)-3(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)$

$\displaystyle=4\{(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^3-3(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta)(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)\}-3\{(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^2-2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\}$

$\displaystyle\implies\dfrac{\cos\alpha}m=1-6(\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2\ \ \ \ (3)$

Similarly, $\displaystyle\dfrac{\sin\alpha}m=-3(\sin\theta\cos\theta)\ \ \ \ (4)$

Compare the values of $(\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2$ from $(3),(4)$ to eliminate $\theta$ and simplify

Comment: @PranavArora, Please have  a look

Comment: Thank you @lab bhattacharjee. This looks nice but I am not able to reach the answer from $(3)$ and $(4)$. I squared $(4)$ and then substituted it in $(3)$ but this doesn't simplify to the given answer. :(

Comment: @PranavArora, I think proper method should dictate answer, not the reverse:).

Comment: I agree, thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

We have, $$\frac{\cos(\alpha-3\theta)}{\cos^3\theta}=\frac{\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin^3\theta}=m$$

Then, $$m=\frac{\sin\theta\cos(\alpha-3\theta)+\cos\theta\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin\theta\cos^3\theta+\cos\theta\sin^3\theta}=\frac{\sin(\alpha-2\theta)}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

Expanding $\sin(\alpha-2\theta)$ and using $2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin2\theta$, we get, $$\frac m2=\sin\alpha\cot2\theta-\cos\alpha\tag1$$

Similarly, $$m=\frac{\cos(\alpha-2\theta)}{\cos^4\theta-\sin^4\theta}=\frac{\cos(\alpha-2\theta)}{\cos2\theta}$$

which gives, $$m=\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\tan2\theta\tag2$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$\left(\frac m2+\cos\alpha\right)\left(m-\cos\alpha\right)=\sin^2\alpha$$ $$\frac{m^2}2+\frac m2\cos\alpha-\cos^2\alpha=\sin^2\alpha$$ $$m^2+m\cos\alpha-2=0.$$

$\square$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I can't actually see how you got either part of your very first step. It looks like you multiplied the original equations by $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ respectively, and added them... but didn't multiply $m$ through? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @EricSnyder ... I have used $\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac{an+cm}{bn+dm}$. If you want a proof, let $\frac ab=\frac cd=k$ .Then $a=kb$ and $c=kd$. Now consider $\frac{an+cm}{bn+dm}$ and it simplifies to $k$. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Ohhhh... OK, that and its simplification are impressively clever. How to get rid of $(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta)$ ? Well, that's just... $1$. I love it.

Comment: @EricSnyder ... you may also find this useful: https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/